# JQGrid server side sorting

Tags: jqgrid

1. How to implement server side sorting in JQgrid, on click of a column
   name.?
2. I have used onSortCol function to do this.
3. On clicking the column name I get the column name and sort order i. e  "asc", then I
       pass it to the controller function and get the response and grid is
       loaded again.
4. But next time when I click again sortorder comes as
           "asc", whereas it should be "desc".

Am I doing it right, is there any way to do server-side sorting.?

How to get "desc" next time?

Comment: Try to remove your `onSortCol`. You will see that jqGrid send the request to the server **automatically**. `sord` parameter gives the direction of sorting and `sidx` gives the name of sorting columns.

Comment: @Oleg I have removed  the "onSortCol" function. But the request is not send to server, it happens on client side. I want to send a request to server with the parameters.

Comment: You can use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or Developer Tools of IE/Chrome to trace HTTP traffic. It helps to see all requests which will be send to the server. you should include JavaScript code which you use. Moreover it's always important to know which version of jqGrid you use.

Comment: I am using chrome. I cannot see any call going to server. On clicking the name i should call a function and send the parameters to the server and get the data.

Comment: **Which version of jqGrid you use? Could you post JavaScript code which you use to create jqGrid?** I suppose that the reason is in the code. If you just use `url: "yourServerUrl", datatype: "json"` (without usage of `loadonce: true`) then jqGrid automatically send to URL the parameters `sidx`, `sord`, `page` and `rows`. If your grid don't do this than you created it in a wrong way.